# Line sequence approximation of closed curve from edge detector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, approximation

I have a large array of 2D points representing the outer edge of a shape delivered by an edge detector. I want to approximate this closed curve by a sequence of straight lines that is preserving the original edge according to some metric like least square and a chosen threshold (which is basically the task of "straight line drawing vectorization" but "vectorization" has a different meaning in Matlab so web search was misleading).
Could someone please propose free Matlab code for this task. Thank you!

Comment: We will not propose "free" Matlab code since this is not a code writing service. It would help if you could provide actual data that we can play around with. If this is only a question of fitting your data to a structure i.e a function, you can take a look at the curve fitting toolbox.

Comment: You might look at polygon simplification.

Comment: You might want to use the Douglas-Peucker algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an edge detector I am using now a [boundary tracer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27639-boundary-tracing-using-the-moore-neighbourhood) to get an ordered coordinate set. Whats left is an adaptive sampling strategy for the coordinates but at the moment a simple strategy like "select every nth coordinate" works good enough.